# Problem understanding a concept in nested while loops in python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

Why isn't the while loop stopping at 4 or 2?

I've tried using the less than or equal sign instead of just the less than sign yet all it did was leave me with even more questions.

```
i = 0 
while i < 4:
    while i < 6:
        i = i + 2
        print(i)
```

I expected the output to be 2 since when the condition of the first while loop becomes false, the loop should exit, or if we don't consider the first statement and just take the second one it should have outputted 4 since in the first and second loop the condition is less than not less than or equal.

The actual results that I'm getting are 2, 4, 6 and I can't figure out why.

**Reply to the comment posted:** No I was expecting the outer loop to exit the moment `i` is equal to 2 as if it is equal to 4 then it is less than or equal although it is supposed to be < not <=.

**Edit:** Thanks guys for the help, I realized how frustrating it is to program while sleep deprived.

Comment: Are you expecting the outer loop to exit the second that `i` is >= 4?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why you're expecting it to exit when it's 2, but not that the condition isn't checked constantly; it's only checked when the execution goes back to the top of the loop. Or in other words, the outer condition will only be checked when the inner loop finishes.

Comment: Thank you but I have one more question, why does 'i' get to 6 isn't it supposed to be less than 6 instead of less than or equal to 6?

Comment: `i` goes from 4 to 6, *then* the condition is checked. The `i < 6` doesn't prevent `i` from ever going over 5; it just means that the loop will terminate once the condition is checked.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, I feel like I made it much harder on myself by overthinking it too much.

Comment: Take a look at this [PythonTutor visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=i%20%3D%200%20%0Awhile%20i%20%3C%204%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20i%20%3C%206%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20%3D%20i%20%2B%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28i%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) of your code. I even took the bother and copied your code there :). By pressing forward, you can see the execution of the code **step-by-step** with the value of `i` in each step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated

Comment: @PR0M37H3U5 Yes, with how you were thinking about it, it would seem more complicated. Wait until you start looping with something other than an `i` index counter. Their use will begin to make more sense as you get more practice with them.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop your condition is smaller than 4, but when you go to next loop, your condition changes. It becomes smaller than 6. Second loop is independent with the first one.